# Cannot scrape a website with BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

The text I'm trying to scrape is the title *123rd Meeting* from

> https://www.bcb.gov.br/en/#!/c/copomstatements/1724

To do so, I use this code

```
import urllib.request           #get the HTML page from url 
import urllib.error

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


# set page to read
with urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.bcb.gov.br/en/#!/c/copomstatements/1724') as response:
   page = response.read()

# parse the html using beautiful soup and store in variable `soup`
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
print(soup)

# Inspect: <h3 class="BCTituloPagina ng-binding">123rd Meeting</h3>
title = soup.find("h3", attrs={"class": "BCTituloPagina ng-binding"})
print(title)
```

However, the command

```
print(soup)
```

doesn't return neither the title: *123rd Meeting* nor the body: *In light of the .... target by 25 basis points.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the normal requests library in python to extract the title, as the element you're trying to extract is rendered with javascript. You will need to use selenium to achieve your goal.

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.bcb.gov.br/en/#!/c/copomstatements/1724')
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//h3')))
title = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h3').text
print(title)
driver.close()
```

Output:

`123rd Meeting`

Comment: Thanks @Ali for the prompt reply. Since

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

opens Google Chrome, and this command will have to be run (in a loop) at least a 100 times, I added the following line to close it

    driver.close()